# ApplicationInsights is not considering json configured log level

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.1, ilogger

Given this appsettings.json

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "foobar",
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And this from `startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("TD");
    var appSettings = new AppSettings();
    new ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection).Configure(appSettings);
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

    services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp";
    });
}
```

Why am I still only seeing Critical, Error and Warning in my AI output?

e.g. from arbitrary logs from a controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(string foobar)
{
    Logger.LogDebug($"Ilogger debug {foobar}");
    Logger.LogInformation($"Ilogger info {foobar}");
    Logger.LogWarning($"Ilogger warning {foobar}");
    Logger.LogError($"Ilogger error {foobar}");
    Logger.LogCritical($"Ilogger critical {foobar}");
}
```

According to the microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#control-logging-level)

> ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider is enabled by default in Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet SDK version 2.7.1 (and later) when you turn on regular Application Insights monitoring through either of the methods:
>
> - By calling the UseApplicationInsights extension method onIWebHostBuilder (Now obsolete)
> - By calling the AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry extension method on IServiceCollection

So I am a bit lost as to why the Debug/Info traces are not being output.

There are no overrides or logging settings in appsettings.development.json.

I am using AppInsights SDK 2.13.1.

Asp NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something wrong with the `appsettings.json`(if you're sure no other place overrides the logging level). The log level for application insights should be placed within the `Logging` element in the .json file(see the official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#create-filter-rules-in-configuration-with-appsettingsjson)).

The correct one should look like this:

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "xxxxx"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And the test result:

[image]

Comment: That did it - moving ApplicationInsights/LogLevel inside the Logging node in appsettings.json. Thanks!

Comment: But is it required to place ApplicationInsights inside logging? Shouldn't the LogLevel and Default setting not apply to all providers including ApplicationInsights? I've noticed if I don't specify ApplicationInsights under Logging then I don't see any Information messages even though this is set ""Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },